# Pyhon Pandas когда таблица не влезает в оперативку

Tags: python, память, pandas, анализ

Что делать, когда таблица не влезает в оперативную память?
использую стандартные:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('data.tsv', sep ='/t')
```

Когда несчастная панда пытается все загрузить по понятным причинам комп виснет.
Возможно ли сделать так, что бы подгружалась только часть таблицы в оперативку?

Очевидные варианты решения: докупи памяти, и арендуй сервер - уже рассматриваю.

Comment: Какой размер файла data.tsv?

Comment: Ответ будет зависить от того, что вы намерены делать с данными... Возможна ли обработка данных по частям (chunks)? Сколько у вас оперативной памяти? Сколько строк и столбцов в CSV и какого они типа (строки, целые, даты, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Если возможно обработать данные по частям, то можно воспользоваться параметром [chunksize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Пример:

```
chunksize=10**5

for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    # process chunk here...
```

Если вам нужен весь DataFrame в памяти и Pandas не позволяет вам этого сделать - можно попробовать воспользоваться [Dask DataFrame](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html), который умеет работать с данными, которые не вмещаются в памяти (часть данных находится на диске) - у них похожий набор функций (хотя API победнее по сравнению с Pandas).

Если же речь идет об огромных данных, то стоит подумать об использовании [Apache Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) в кластере.